# Discrete Math determine if this is function without graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether or not the following relations define a function? $\{(x,y)\mid x,y∈Q,x^2+y^2=1\}$?

Comment: Can you find more than one $y$ corresponding to any $x$?

Comment: Each x corresponds to only one y value, but how can i explain it in this set notation?, I understand it is a circle, but is there way I can explain it using set notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that both of (1/$\sqrt{2}$,1/$\sqrt{2}$) and (1/$\sqrt{2}$,-1/$\sqrt{2}$) are present in the relation, which violates the definition of function. Hence it's not a function.

Comment: Im new to this site thanks,awesome that makes sense!!

Comment: @user149068 If you are satisfied with my answer you can click on the accept button, so that it indicates you have got your answer.